# Multiple tabbed panels in Google Earth Engine app?

Tags: google-earth-engine

How can I add multiple tabbed panels to a Google Earth Engine app?

I don't see an option for this in the [docs](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/guides/ui_panels#panels).

My app has two components, data visualisation, and some options to download points for ground truthing. All the components together means users would have to scroll up and down quite a bit in the panel, but having multiple tabbed panels would solve this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no tabs in the UI interface, but you can do split panels, which might help.

```
var panel1 = ui.Panel([ui.Label("This is panel 1")])
var panel2 = ui.Panel([ui.Label("This is panel 2")])
var split = ui.SplitPanel(panel1, panel2, "vertical")
ui.root.insert(0, split)
```

https://code.earthengine.google.com/54de23488ab7bc0b06d7fc0fde9cde76